# Enable Copy/paste across different applications

Tags: java, textbox, swt, clipboard, copy-paste

The default context menu of SWT `Text` in windows has several options that we did not want. As the default context menu is provided by the operating system and cannot be modified, I created a custom context menu with only basic Text operations such as delete, cut, copy and paste for the Text boxes.

[image: Custom Text context Menu]

The problem now is that when I copy text from another application and try pasting into the TextBox, the paste doesn't seem to work. But it works when we copy/cut text within the application itself.

Here is the code for copy and paste.
Paste Action:

```
private class PasteActionHandler extends Action {

    /** Creates a new instance. */
    private PasteActionHandler() {
        ...
        setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void runWithEvent(Event event) {
        if (activeTextControl != null && !activeTextControl.isDisposed()) {
            activeTextControl.paste();
            updateActionsEnableState();
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the state of the Paste Action.
     */
    public void updateEnabledState() {
        if (activeTextControl != null && !activeTextControl.isDisposed()) {
            boolean canPaste = false;
            if (activeTextControl.getEditable()) {
                Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(activeTextControl.getDisplay());
                TransferData[] td = clipboard.getAvailableTypes();
                for (int i = 0; i < td.length; ++i) {
                    if (TextTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(td[i])) {
                        canPaste = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                clipboard.dispose();
            }
            setEnabled(canPaste);
            return;
        }
        setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Copy Action:

```
private class CopyActionHandler extends Action {

    private CopyActionHandler() {
        ...
        setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void runWithEvent(Event event) {
        if (activeTextControl != null && !activeTextControl.isDisposed()) {
            activeTextControl.copy();
            updateActionsEnableState();
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the state of the {@link Action}.
     */
    public void updateEnabledState() {
        if (activeTextControl != null && !activeTextControl.isDisposed()) {
            setEnabled(activeTextControl.getSelectionCount() > 0);
            return;
        }
        setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

As you could see, I call the Text control's copy and paste functions to do the operations.
Also is there a way in SWT to get the system clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

To copy something in the clipboard from SWT i use the code:

```
    String textData = textControl.getText();
    if (textData.length() > 0) {
      org.eclipse.swt.dnd.Clipboard cb = new org.eclipse.swt.dnd.Clipboard(display);
      org.eclipse.swt.dnd.TextTransfer textTransfer = org.eclipse.swt.dnd.TextTransfer.getInstance();
      cb.setContents(new Object[]{textData}, new Transfer[]{textTransfer});
    }
```

you can try that instead of `activeTextControl.copy()` function and see if it works